# Ellipsis or no?

Tags: ellipsis

Is there anything missing from this sentence:

> Da ist jemand nicht gut, auf Sie zu sprechen.

This is from an episode of Die Chefin. I tried to complete it with:

> Da ist jemand, der es nicht gut macht, wenn er auf Sie zu sprechen.

but that did not seem correct either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there anything missing from this sentence:
>
> > Da ist jemand nicht gut, auf Sie zu sprechen.

Quite the contrary. There is something too much, and it is the *comma*. The phrase

> auf jemand nicht gut zu sprechen sein
>
> <sub>(to be ill-posed / not well disposed towards someone)</sub>

is a fixed expression. So, the sentence should be

> Da ist jemand nicht gut auf Sie zu sprechen.
>
> <sub>(Someone is not well disposed towards you.)</sub>